# TokBox screen sharing audio is not working

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I'm using the TokBox / OpenTok screen sharing API for web browser, and when publishing a screen I'm using "publishAudio: true", but the subscriber does not receive any audio. The subscriber does receive the screen video though.

Does anyone know how to solve this audio issue? I'm using Google Chrome on macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need see more of you concrete case code but i hope this can help you.

You need to send the audioSource. Example:

```
if (videoSource) { // in my case, i'm using null or 'screen'
  opts.videoSource = videoSource;
}

console.log('micStream getAudioTracks:');
console.log(micStream.getAudioTracks());

opts.audioSource = micStream.getAudioTracks()[0]; //you can choose you audio source
const target = document.getElementById(targetId);

const pub = OT.initPublisher(target, opts, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('err');
    reject(err);
  } else {
    console.log('resolve');
    resolve(pub);
  }
});
```

I

Comment: Thanks! I talked to OpenTok support, and found that audio needs to be published separately like in this example. My use case is to capture system audio (e.g. YouTube video audio) and share it along with the screen. But not sure how do this yet; might have to write a Google Chrome extension or write a native app instead of a web app.